# Solving for unknowns in a linear system with variables represented by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am attempting to solve a system of linear equations represented by a matrix, where I am given certain known values and need to solve for the unknowns. The matrix representation of my system involves resistances $R_1$ and $R_2$, a known voltage $V_1$, and I need to solve for the current $i_1$ and another voltage $v_2$. The system is structured as follows:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  R_1 + R_2 & 0 & V_1\\
  R_2 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

So far, by manipulating the first row by dividing the row by $R_1+R_2$, I've deduced that $i_1 = V_1 / (R_1 + R_2)$, but I'm unsure how to proceed to solve for $v_2$ by transforming the matrix into a reduced row echelon form.

Perhaps someone could help me out?

Comment: Divide the first row by $R_1 + R_2$

Comment: Yes, I've done that, but the confusing bit is the second row

Comment: Reduced row echelon form.... Much simpler: you know $i_1\,.$ What does this mean for  the second equation that you must solve for $i_2\,?$

Comment: Now subtract a multiple of the first row from the second. If you do it the right way, $i_2$ does not appear in the resulting row.

Comment: Boys and girls! We know $i_1\,.$ By the second equation $i_2=i_1R_2\,.$ Hence we know $i_2\,.$ Apart from being *lower* triangular I would say that the matrix has row echelon form and nothing needs to be done to it to solve for the unknowns.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt notice that it was lower triangular, I solved it now :)